# Changes in one Object should affect the other objects of same class

Tags: ios, design-patterns, delegates, singleton, customization

Currently I'm working on an iOS project. In which I have two visually similar objects derived from same class. Want I want is when I do some changes on one object that need to change the same in object 2.

**In detail:**

I have a class `MyClass` and `obj1` and `obj2` are derived from `MyClass`. When I do some actions on `obj1` it'll call the corresponding delegate method of `obj1`. Now what I want is when the `obj1` calls it's delegate method, I also need to call the delegate method of `obj2`. Same like: if I changes `obj2` it'll affect the `obj1`. Also I need to add more element in future.

**What I did:**

I added a Singleton class and placed a array on it and added the objects to that.

And in the delegate method:

```
- (void)delegateMethod:(id)param
{
   NSMutableArray *arr = [[MySingleTon sharedObject] getArray];
   for(int loop = 0;loop<[arr count];loop++)
   {
      if(![arr objectAtIndex] == self)
      {
          [[arr objectAtIndex:loop] delegateMethod:param];
      }
   }
}
```

**What happened is:**

But the issue is it will cause an infinite loop. The Obj2 will do the same thing and all other object do the same thing. I'm stuck here, I have about 25 delegate methods and need to implement the same functionality. I can't change the delegate method by adding an extra parameter.

Is there any solution for this ?  Please help me, thanks in advance.

**Why I need this/Actual implementation:**

I created a custom view which can be zoomed/rotated etc. I created two objects of same class and added it to my parent view. Now when I change anything on view 1 it should change the similar in view 2. Also I need to add more views.

Answer (score 1):

Basically because you want to have two different objects refer to exactly the same state you should point those two objects at a third - be that a base class with static state or a third type with static state or that is a singleton. This has the benefit that Object1 doesn't have to know about Object2 which means if you ever add an Object3 then you don't have to change your code.

So whenever your objects write to the shared state that new value is available to be read. If you want the objects to alter immediately on that change then you'll need to implement events (which I assume iOS has) in order to have Object1 and Object2 subscribe to changes in shared state.

I don't iOS but in pseduocode...

```
abstract class BaseClass {
 protected static sharedArray = new sharedArray();

  void someMethod(int i, int aNewValue) {
   BaseClass.sharedArray[i] = aNewValue;
  }

  int getSharedValue(int i) {
    return BaseClass.sharedArray[i];
  }
}

class ObjectOne extends BaseClass {

}

class ObjectTwo extends BaseClass {

}
```

Please note this isn't threadsafe and is a bit awful but it might point you in the right direction. It would be much tidier (but still not threadsafe) if the state you are referencing was held by a singleton which each of the objects referenced

```
//this isn't written as a singleton
class MySingleton {
    private SharedArray sharedArray = new sharedArray();

    void someMethod(int i, int aNewValue) {
       BaseClass.sharedArray[i] = aNewValue;
    }

    int getSharedValue(int i) {
       return BaseClass.sharedArray[i];
    }
}

class ObjectOne extends MyCustomViewObjectThing {
     private MySingleton mySingleton

     void doMyChangeActivity(int i) {
       mySingleton.someMethod(i, i);
     }
}

class ObjectTwo extends MyCustomViewObjectThing {
     private MySingleton mySingleton

     void doMyChangeActivity(int i) {
       mySingleton.someMethod(i, i*2);
     }      
}
```

I know this code is awful but it's only intended to illustrate what I mean :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. When your changes in the Object1 then you manually call the delegate method of Object2. So when you manually called a delegate method of Object2 you already have parameter in that delegate method so in your parameter list add one more parameter that will indicate from which object this method is called. So by using that parameter that if your main object1 is changed and your are calling Object2's delegate method manually and by putting on condition you can come out of the problem.

Hope this will help you.

If still you want any help i am here.

All the best !!!

Comment: From where I call the delegate method of other objects ? Also In future I'll be adding more objects of same class. Then it'll be difficult to handle (adding individual calls).